# Update single row in a table using entity framework

Tags: c#, webforms, entity-framework-6

I'm new at using EF6 in webforms. I'm trying to update the only row available in a table that has no ID, it's just a parameters configurations table for the application.

I have this update method on the formview. It gives me error when i try to load the item. I think i'm doing it wrong here though but not sure what do i need to do. I no nothing about linq.

> Error 11  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'InventarioCiclico.xInventarioConfigs'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    C:\Users\A0H79224\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\InventarioCiclico\InventarioCiclico\Account\Admin\ConfigurarInventario.aspx.cs  73  20  InventarioCiclico

```
 // The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the control
    public void fvInventarioConfigs_UpdateItem(xInventarioConfigs configs)
    {

        InventarioCiclico.xInventarioConfigs item = configs;

        InventarioCiclicoContext context = new InventarioCiclicoContext();

        // Load the item here, e.g. item = MyDataLayer.Find(id);
        item = (from c in context.xInventarioConfigs select c).Take(1);
        if (item == null)
        {
            // The item wasn't found
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id was not found"));
            return;
        }

        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
            // Save changes here, e.g. MyDataLayer.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take** returns an **IQueryable** even if you select only one record by using **Take(1)**. You can use something like this as a quick fix:

```
item = (from c in context.xInventarioConfigs select c).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or even without Take as FirstOrDefault selects one row anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Take returns an IQueryable which *might* only contain one item but still is a collection of sorts. If you select only one record by using Take(1) you might as well go for First (careful here if there is none in your result set) or FirstOrDefault directly

```
item = (from c in context.xInventarioConfigs select c).FirstOrDefault();
```